# How do you turn off suggestions when adding a new event in calendar?

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

I would like to disable suggestions in the Calendar app on my iphone.  Since my last update, if I add a new event and start typing it flashes through lots of suggestions.  This makes it difficult to add the event you are trying to add, as often I cannot scroll past these to fill out the event, and if you accidentally touch one of the suggestions while you try and scroll you have to delete and start over.

I have seen this question asked in a few places, but no responses, so I suspect this "feature" is something you can't control, but if anyone has found a way to turn this off I'd like to know.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/273343/how-do-you-turn-off-suggestions-when-adding-a-new-event-in-calendar
I agree. Please Apple can you deal with this problem!

Answer (score 2):

Currently you can't disable these suggestions when creating an event.

The only calendar suggestions you can disable are the location suggestions and the event suggestions detected from other apps on your device. You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html